Fair information distribution when splitting a QR code
I am trying to understand the impact on information distribution when splitting a QR code into two equal parts. Specifically I am looking at fairness of the distribution: a perfectly fair split in that sense would be that exactly 50% of data is available in each half of the split.
What would approximately be the most fair (assuming a low level of error correction, if that helps) way to split? Vertically? Horizontally? Diagonally?
